# TextBox onchange event is frining twice with placeholder in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have added a placeholder to the Textbox using below link,

http://www.techken.in/coding/c-wpf-create-textbox-placeholder-using-xaml-code/

Below is the textbox syntax i used,

```
<TextBox   Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}"  Tag="Input text" Text="
{Binding Path=Token,Mode=OneWayToSource, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event 
TextChanged] = [Action OnChangeEvent()]"  />
```

When placeHolder is kept event is firing twice. If I remove UpdateSourceTrigger for Textbox which is inside of placeHolder xaml I could not get the changed property value. Anyone please let me know how I can make this to hit OnChangeEvent once only with placeholder.

Comment: Can't reproduce the behaviour. I think it has something to do with Calibrum Micro that you are using with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the value in the property setter so the property is not set twice causing the OnChangeEvent to fire twice. try below way

**if (value == _token) return;**

```
public string Token
{
    get => _token;
    set
    {
        if (value == _token)
        { 
            return;
        }
        _token = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: By this way we cannot use 'cal: Message.Attach="[Event 
TextChanged]' event where we have so many options like passing these parameters(        //$eventArgs,$dataContext,$source,$view,$executionContext,$this
).But this works for me currently.

Comment: If gating the change breaks attaching to the message you might want to consider removing the gate and playing around with the UpdateSourceTrigger instead. Change the trigger to explicit and try gating the value there.